# Add google reCAPTCHA to ExtJS component

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, recaptcha

I am trying to put google recaptcha within extjs application but it is not getting rendered.

```
{
    xtype:'panel',
    width:300,
    height:60,
    html:'<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="MyKey" data-callback="correctCaptcha"></div>'
}
```

Comment: Hello, I was assigned the task of putting a captcha, but I don't know anything about extjs, it managed to advance with your comment, but I'm not quite sure what to do with the secret key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, using google recaptha with ExtJS is something like this:

1. Load recaptha code, add

   ```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer>
   </script>
   ```

in appropriate place in your code.

2. Add recaptcha to any component, like this:

   ```
   {
       xtype: 'box',
       id: 'myCaptcha',
       listeners: {
           'afterrender': function () {
               grecaptcha.render('myCaptcha', {
                   'sitekey': 'your_site_key'
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

You have to do it within , for example, `afterrender` listener because when you just define your ExtJS component related DOM elements not added to document elements yet.

*And if someone looking for it - [Google reCAPTCHA guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro#audience).*

Comment: I am getting following error with the above code, 'ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined'

Comment: Than you added script from part 1 wrong. Make sure it is executed before ExtJS code.

Comment: Hello, I was assigned the task of putting a captcha, but I don't know anything about extjs, it managed to advance with your comment, but I'm not quite sure what to do with the secret key.